# Drupal 8, use "query api" with "collection fields" (not via FieldCollectionItem::load)

Tags: 8, entities

I added a field collection to the user 'manage field' page, the field machine name is 'houses'. The user may add as many home he want.

This field collection regroup :

```
- a sample text plain field (the name of the house), the machine name "house_name"
- a sample integer field (the size of the house), the machine name "house_size"
```

In a custom module, I want check if the current user have a house with a size = 4 (if in collection fields, there is a house with "house_size = 4"), how can I do that via the Drupal 8 Query Api ?

I found several example of Drupal "Query API", but nothing with collections fields..

I can use the function load of the class FieldCollectionItem, but I want use a fastest way for get the information I want.

Thanks you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to query the fields of the `FieldCollectionItem` with `.entity`:

```
 $user_ids = \Drupal::entityQuery('user')
    ->condition('houses.entity.house_size', 4)
    ->execute();
```